# Подробная информация об изображении

Tags: php

Как получить подробную информацию о фотографии (предполагаемые файлы *.jpg) средствами php? Прим.: вспышка, дата создания, координаты и т.п.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Exif Reader](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Image-Galleries/PHP-Exif-Reader-3214.html)

Экзиф надо читать.
ЗЫ: если ссыль НЕ работает, гуглите по запросу:
Exif reader
By Richard James Kendall

Кстати. На некоторые хостинги-таки ставят родную читалку Exif для PHP.
В таком случае, все сводится к изучению [Функций этого модуля](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exif.php)